# Nginx Reverse Proxy intermittently returns 404

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm developing what I thought would be a straightforward Nginx reverse proxy. Its goal is to forward/proxy all requests to another load balancer (ALB) behind which static assets reside. The traffic on the proxy is expected to be minimal and currently it is receiving only test traffic (one user at a time).

Details:

- Deployed on EC2 instance (m5.xlarge).

  - amzn-linux 2: CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
  - Docker Compose version v2.13.0
  - Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
  - Nothing else weird has been done setting it up (just enough to get docker and docker-compose working). No other services run on it.
- EC2 instance is inside a target group, behind an AWS ALB. It is currently the only instance in the target group
- It is currently run by ssh'ing to the box and using `docker-compose up -d`
- It is the latest nginx image

**When it first starts, everything is great. No errors. Then, approximately 1-3 days later it begins returning 404's *intermittently*.** Sometimes it is on the index.html initial load, sometimes on static assets like .js, .css, or image files. Every time I refresh the page, there are usually 2-3 404s and on different requests each time. The rest of the files return 200s. From the logs below, it appears to happen on almost every other request.

If I let it sit for several hours, it continuously occurs. It does not "resolve itself".

Workaround/Fix:

- Restart the docker-compose just doing a docker-compose `down` then `up`. **I do nothing else to fix it.** Restarting immediately fixes the problem until 1-3 days later it begins happening again.

**Examples from `docker-compose logs`:**

```
nginx  | 10.0.51.10 - - [10/Sep/2023:01:58:55 +0000] "GET /dataportal/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1706 "https://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com/dataportal/dashboards" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
nginx  | 10.0.51.10 - - [10/Sep/2023:01:58:55 +0000] "GET /dataportal/static/css/main.3fb3fe79.css HTTP/1.1" 200 86129 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
nginx  | 10.0.51.10 - - [10/Sep/2023:01:58:55 +0000] "GET /dataportal/static/js/main.5c5d85b7.js HTTP/1.1" 404 967 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
nginx  | 10.0.51.10 - - [10/Sep/2023:01:58:56 +0000] "GET /api/dataportal/dashboards HTTP/1.1" 200 2043 "https://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com/dataportal/dashboards" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
nginx  | 10.0.52.62 - - [10/Sep/2023:01:58:57 +0000] "GET /dataportal/static/css/main.51fa6b06.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1706 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AkamaiImageServer VelocitudeMP/1.0;IM/1.0"
nginx  | 10.0.51.10 - - [10/Sep/2023:01:58:57 +0000] "GET /dataportal/static/js/main.d4bbd5f8.js HTTP/1.1" 404 967 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AkamaiImageServer VelocitudeMP/1.0;IM/1.0"
```

There are no errors in docker-compose logs besides the 404's.

**~/nginx.conf file:**

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
  
    location = /health {
            access_log off;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json';
            return 200 '{"status":"UP"}';
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
 }
}
```

**~/docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: "3"
services:

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      #- "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I've tried:

1. I've checked that the docker-compose is still running. Nothing in logs beyond the 200 and 404 status calls.
2. I verified that no one else is accessing/modifying the server/container.
3. I've restarted the docker-compose, which works for 1-3 days. I've done this three times and each time it temporarily fixes it. Then it begins happening again.
4. I've checked `top` for CPU/memory and `df` for disk space while it is returning 404s. `Top` shows basically no usage anywhere, as expected. Disk usage is at 30%. EC2 instance is healthy and Cloudwatch monitoring shows no issues.
5. Downstream ALB has healthy resources that don't report issues. Since it is temporarily "fixed" when I restart the docker-compose reverse proxy, that seems to me to isolate it to that service.

The fact that this is intermittent confuses me. And given how it works great for a day then degrades over time, I would expect it to be a resource issue, but as I mentioned there is basically zero load and resources seem abundant.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!